Deep Copy of Delta Table modified Commit Timestamp
I have a delta table and copy the complete folder including the log folder to a different directory.
When running
DESCRIBE HISTORY eventsTable

I see the history with the same version numbers and changes, but with a timestamp that is obviously the data of copy for all operations.
Why does the timestamp column change? Shouldn't it be taken from the transaction log?
